# Non-Permanent Plastic Pipe Sealant or Join Improvement?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, sealant

**Brief:** Looking for recommendations on a product to improve the seal of 2 joined plastic pipes (narrower pipe wedged into wider one) that is non-permanent + water and hot/cold resistant?

**Details:** I have two plastic pipes (similar to PVC pipe) which is part of an Enersol solar pool heating panel that fit together, one into the other with a locking pin to hold them together. The fit is too loose and they leak constantly (we have had endless problems with these).

As far as I can tell they are not damaged, just that the pipes don't fit snug enough. I want to make the seal better, but it can't be permenantly cemented together because if one panel needs to be replaced they have to come apart.

I was about to try a wrap of teflon-tape around the inner pipe and try that, but it occurred to me that there might be a product meant specifically for this. Needs to be waterproof, and fairly heat/cold resistant. It is on the roof.

[image: photo of pipe joint]

Disclaimer: we are not handy at all.

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to me that since it is on the roof, subject to extremes, that the joint needs to withstand the expansion and contraction of the PVC pipe. That joint you are referring to is just that, it is a slip joint that allows the pipe to grow and shrink in length and presumably still not leak, since is a closed system, or supposed to be. There should be a rubber or neoprene "O" ring that allows it to seal with movement. It should just need replacement and reassembled using a silicone lubricant.

Comment: Some research reveals that the panels do have a specific o-ring inside this connection. I will look into cleaning and replacing these... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a rubber pipe repair coller with supplied hose clamps that are sold in every hardware store or even wally worlds plumbing department.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a product called [seal all] comes in a tube,gas,oil,water,far as I no resistant to pretty much everything.Ive used it on many different projects and has never failed.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinary silicone **bathroom sealant** isn't particularly adhesive, and a good tug should separate the parts if required (assuming you use just enough to make a seal); the rest should peal off.  If you want it to stick well, it's a good idea to clean and degrease the surface(s) first, using methylated spirits (denatured alcohol). Alternatively you can use it to cast a seal in place: Clean one side of the joint as above, then coat the other with a thin, even smear of grease (e.g. Vaseline).  Glue with bathroom sealant.  When the sealant dries, it should have stuck to the cleaned side and not the greased side.